# Click divided image(not as a square) and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm in a student web game project team. I am using `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` for our project. I'm wondering how can I divide an image for click and change it.

**Consider the following image as our example:**

[image]

The circle has 3 parts, and they have to be changed if they are clicked, but I cannot find how to divide the image like that. Whenever the user clicks a part, I want it to highlight the section like this:

[image]

This came up from some old flash games, like game map or pizza game. Thank you for reading this!

Comment: would you mind  posting your Code what you have tried?

Comment: If you want to give multiple links to image then, you can use image map.

Comment: If you want to give multiple links to image then, you can use image map.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have to use images but if not, it can be done like this:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slice {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.slice-contents {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.slice:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(1) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
.slice:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(2) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
.slice:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(30deg) scale(1.2);
}
.slice:nth-child(3) .slice-contents {
  transform: skewY(-30deg); 
}
.slice:nth-child(3) .slice-contents:active {
  background: lightblue;
}
.inner-pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class='circle'>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'></div>
  </li>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'></div>
  </li>
  <li class='slice'>
    <div class='slice-contents'></div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create sectors in a division and use them for dividing circles.
here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tg5jybb9/

all you need to do is toggle b/w `click events`  using jquery or javascript